# Insert into table values from another table and show the values from another table

Tags: sql

I want to do a select into with select but i need to show the values from the select. I tried this:

```
Insert into (column1,column2,column3) select column1,column2,column3 from table;
select column1,column2,column3 from table;
```

But terminal said that the relation of second select doesn't exist.

I am breaking my head with this. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Don't tag spam; just tag the RDBMS you are *really* using and only that one.

Comment: INSERT INTO needs in the table name the data to be inserted into.

Comment: insert into targettable select ... from ...

Answer (score 0):

Inserting and selecting rows are two different queries, so there is no type of query like "select into with select". Target table name is missing in your insertion query;

```
Insert into target_table(column1,column2,column3) select column1,column2,column3 from source_table;
select column1,column2,column3 from source_table;
```

Comment: Sorry!! I forgot to put the source name in the question and i thought i expressed wrong. I wanted to say that I can't insert into the values from other table and after show the source_table in terminal. I don't know if exists a way to do this.

Comment: I'm not sure which tool you are using. If you can insert the values by selecting, and than you can select the values from source_table (in two different steps), maybe the tool you are using is not allow you to do that in one step.

Comment: I'm using postgresql but the code I put is a attempt I tried but it didn't work. I want to insert and select in one step because i don't know a way to do in two or more. The example query I put give me an error that say the relation of source_table doesn't exist :(

Comment: The lines in my answer are two different steps, try to run them separately.

Comment: Yes but I need run it in the same sql file